# benefitting patients with X/ benefits patients with X

Tags: adjectives, syntactic-analysis, sentence, gerunds

I am struggling with analysing the sentence 'Y happens, benefitting patients with X'.

I can see that 'Y benefits patients with X' uses the present tense simple form of the verb.

But in the first example, is 'benefitting' functioning as a gerund or an adjective?

Comment: BillJ gives the CGEL analysis at [Is it a gerund or a verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/341524/is-it-a-gerund-or-a-verb/341580#341580): << ...  In _I saw them killing the birds_, "killing" is ... a verb since it has "birds" as direct object. And in _I witnessed the killing of the birds_, "killing" is a noun, as evidenced by the determiner "the" and the of- phrase complement. ,,, >> Here, 'patients with X' is a DO (I've changed the question slightly to reflect my belief that condition and remedy etc are distinct). But there are more comprehensive answers in other threads.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When does a gerund 'become' a verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/346877/when-does-a-gerund-become-a-verb) Or this? [should gerund + 'objective' be modified by adjective or adverb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/435916/should-gerund-objective-be-modified-by-adjectives-or-adverbs/436913#436913). In the question above, the ing-form is unquestionably [very-close-to-verb-end-of-continuum] or as many would decree [verb]. Certainly not an adjective; 'gerund' is ill-defined.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am still not sure how this fits in with the example: 'Accordingly, a focus on X will lead to X, ultimately benefiting patients with X.' Here, I do not see how it functions as a verb. If I change the sentence: 'Benefiting patients with X, the focus of the study is X.' Does this still mean it is functioning as a verb?

Comment: The acceptability of modification by adverb in the original is another fair test for verbness, in addition to the presence of the direct object: [adverb] [ing-form] [DO]. // Perhaps you're involving too much semantic analysis in deciding what a verb actually is. A 'doing word' (Joe hit Bob). But 'own', 'seem' stretch this concept. There needs to be far more syntactic analysis in defining verbness. Distribution (acceptance of a typical adverb say) is an important factor. Another is morphology/inflection. // ...

Comment: 'Benefitting patients' in the participle clause can be compared with '... and this is really benefitting patients' to show a 'verby' usage. Perhaps [would have trouble imagining ... is this present participle or ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91929/would-have-trouble-imagining-is-this-present-participle-or-gerund/91933#91933) will help.

Comment: The original sentence can be viewed as "Y happening is benefitting patients with X"

Comment: Thank you so much for your help with this question. I appreciate the various responses.